# How to update budget name , amount and biddingStrategyType of Campaign budget in Google AdWords API?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-java-client, adwords-budgetservice

I already have a campaign budget which i want to update using google AdWords API.

```
   BudgetServiceInterface budgetService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, BudgetServiceInterface.class);

    // Create a budget, which can be shared by multiple campaigns.
    Budget sharedBudget = new Budget();
    sharedBudget.setName("Interplanetary Cruise #" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    Money budgetAmount = new Money();
    budgetAmount.setMicroAmount(50_000_000L);
    sharedBudget.setAmount(budgetAmount);
    sharedBudget.setDeliveryMethod(BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod.STANDARD);

    BudgetOperation budgetOperation = new BudgetOperation();
    budgetOperation.setOperand(sharedBudget);
    budgetOperation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

    // Add the budget
    Long budgetId =
        budgetService.mutate(new BudgetOperation[] {budgetOperation}).getValue(0).getBudgetId();

    // Get the CampaignService.
    CampaignServiceInterface campaignService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, CampaignServiceInterface.class);
```

Assiging budgetId to campaign

```
    Budget budget = new Budget();
    budget.setBudgetId(budgetId);
    campaign.setBudget(budget);
```

This will unassign existing campaign budget and assign new campaign budget to the campaign ( campaign budget is not removed and it still exist in google ads) but I want to update the budget name and budget amount of existing campaign budget rather than assigning new campaign budget.

Answer (score 0):

Use BudgetService to do it. you can find more details in the documentation

```
        $budget = new Budget();
        $budget->setBudgetId(BUDGET_ID);
        $budget->setStatus(BudgetBudgetStatus::REMOVED);            
        $operation = new BudgetOperation();
        $operation->setOperand($budget);
        $operation->setOperator(Operator::SET);
        $operations[] = $operation;
```